# Vectors and Points isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Why we can't use matrices directly for vector calculations , but we must presuppose the isomorphism between R^n and the vectorial space of n dimension ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: How would you use matrices for “vector calculations” when the elements of the vector space are polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not altogether clear to me what you're asking, but I will do my best to interpret your question.

If we have some basis $\beta= \{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ for $\Bbb R^n$, then with respect to that basis, matrices will have a certain form: given a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, the matrix for $T$ with respect to $\beta$ is the matrix denoted $M_\beta^\beta(T)$, to indicate that the domain and codomain share the same basis. If we want to perform matrix-vector operations with this matrix (like apply the matrix $M_\beta^\beta$ to a column vector), then we must make sure that our vectors $v\in\Bbb R^n$ are written with respect to this basis $\beta$, and not some other basis $\alpha$.

Now, if we choose another basis $\alpha = \{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ for $\Bbb R^n$, the matrix $M_\alpha^\alpha(T)$ will not be the same, though $M_\beta^\beta$ and $M_\alpha^\alpha$ represent the same linear transformation.

The two matrices are related by the equation
$$
M_\alpha^\alpha = P^{-1}M_\beta^\beta P
$$
where $P$ is the matrix whose $j$th column is determined by solving the equation
$$
w_j = \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}u_i
$$
for the $p_{ij}$ and then writing the $j$th column as
$$
\text{$j$th column of $P$}=\begin{bmatrix} p_{1j}\\\vdots\\ p_{ij}\\\vdots\\ p_{nj}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $P$ is the *change of basis matrix* and represents the isomorphism $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ that sends the $\alpha$ basis to the $\beta$ basis.